# Protractor : Find Element by ID with spaces

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I've got a button with the following ID

```
<button id="Emp Btn"....
```

I'm unable to access it because of the space

I've tried the following and they don't work

```
element(by.id("Emp Btn"));

element(by.id("Emp%20Btn"));

element(by.id("Emp%Btn"));

element(by.id('Emp Btn'));
```

Comment: HTML 5 says, that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: ouch, thank you. Lemme fix the ID

Answer (score 4):

its bad idea to use spaces in ID. **HTML 5 says, that an id** must contain at least one character and **must not contain space characters.**

But **you still can find such element** using XPath.
Try to use something like this:

```
.\\button[contains(@id,'firstPart') and contains(@id,'secondPart')]
```